# SSL authentication with android and an external certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl

I need to do this thing:

1. communicate using ssl from android terminal to a server;
2. each android client has its own certificate (we can say mutual authentication);
3. the ssl certificate must not be in the application (each person install his certificate on his phone).

How can I do it?
Obviously point 1) alone is easy (I build a keystore/truststore as explained in stackoverflow). The problem is in point 3).

Thanks,
Mario

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Android 4.0 (ICS), you can use the system key store via the `KeyChain` API. For other versions, users need save their keystore somewhere (on the SD card/external storage, etc.) and let your app know where to find it.

Comment: Thanks, I need to use android 2.3. So you are saying that I can read the keystore as a "normal" file?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is a valid PKCS#12 or BKS keystore with a private key and certificate.